# Item List for Text RPG

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple text-based RPG to keep my skills sharp between semesters. I'm trying to create the different elements separately before bringing them together. Right now, I'm trying to create a basic generic list to hold "Item" objects for the player (things like potions and bombs etc.).

[image]

As you can see in the image, I'm trying to tie the index values to the individual items in the list. Since I added the same item to the list three times, it shows up three times (which is what I want), but I'm wondering how I can have this and somehow have the index value represent that actual number of items instead of just the true index value of the objects added.

Essentially, I want to be able to have the player select a number and then use the item that way. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop instead of a for-each loop so you have access to a counter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerItems.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + ". " + playerItems.get(i).getName());
}
```

Or, just use the ctr variable you already have and increment for each item.

```
for (Item i : playerItems)
{
    ctr+=1;
    System.out.println(ctr + ". " + playerItems.get(i).getName());
}
```

Also, you don't need to check if playerItems contains i. You will never get an item in a for-each loop that isn't in the collection.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. I appreciate it!